# Why didn't the curse break when Shrek kissed Fiona?

Tags: shrek, shrek-forever-after

If the spell breaks at true love's first kiss, then when Shrek kissed Fiona, why didn't she turn human again?

Answer (score 11):

Shrek works it out shortly afterwards. It's not just the kiss that's required, there also needs to be a *reciprocated* emotional element.

> **Donkey:** *Maybe you kissed her wrong?*
>
> **Shrek:** *No. The kiss didn't work...because Fiona doesn't love me.*